# 3-way to smart 2-way switch, result is hardwired either on or off

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

At the top and bottom of some stairs are two connected light switches (a 3-way switch).

The **top** switch has:

- bare copper ground
- unused white neutral (in back of box; two wires in a wire nut)
- 2x black wires
- red wire

the **bottom** switch has:

- bare copper ground
- black wire
- white wire
- red wire

My goal is to remove the bottom switch and replace the top switch with a new switch which requires a neutral connection.

(My original plan was to replace the existing switches with a brand of smart switches that require a neutral for both the main and secondary switch. Since the bottom switch doesn't have a neutral, I've decided to instead hard-wire and plate over the bottom switch, then surface-mount a battery-powered smart touch switch in that location.)

**So far...**

In both switches: I'm assuming the red wire is the traveler wire, and have capped it off in both switches.

In the bottom switch: I used a wire nut to hard-wire the black and white wire together. The copper ground is just hanging loose in the box.

As-is, the top switch operates the light as expected.

**The problem:**

When I replace the top switch the switch is unresponsive and the light is hard-wired either on or off (depending on wiring).

If it matters, the switch is:

> GE Z-Wave Plus Wireless Smart Lighting Control Smart Dimmer (model # 14294 )

(and in my defense I've put in 4 of these exact switches elsewhere without issue.)

The important part of the switch, I think, is that it requires, and is wired as:

- ground (connected to bare copper)
- neutral (connected by adding a short wire into the existing wire nut in the box where the white lines were connected to each other)
- load (one of the black wires)
- line (the other black wire)

I'm not sure which black line is which, so I took a guess, then flipped them when that didn't work.

In one position, the switch is non-responsive (and its LED is off) and the ceiling light is on. In the other position, the switch is still non-responsive (and LED off) and the light is off.

(In the meantime, I've put the old switch back in at the top and it works as a normal 2-way switch.)

Photo of original top switch wiring:
[image: added: photo of original top switch wiring]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the light that these switches control?

Comment: Also how old is this construction?  (Thinking California 3-way for those wondering why I’d ask)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's a ceiling light, I haven't touched it yet so I don't have any pictures of its wiring, but I'll take some when I have a chance...

Comment: @Tyson late 1980s construction. Of the 7 switches I've touched so far I've only found one without an unused neutral in the back of the box

Comment: In the bottom switch which color is connected to common on the switch?  (Common has a different color screw).  In the top box what does that color do?

Comment: I'm making an assumption that the black, white, red and bare at the bottom are all coming out of the same cable or Romex?

Comment: Colors mean almost nothing.  They mean *less than nothing* in 3-way circuits.    How are they grouped into cables? **What is the color of the screws the wires land on?**

Comment: Also, neutrals in the back of the box are not unused, they are working hard.  And messenger is not singular, despite what you may have read on your smartswitch diagram.  **Messengers are in pairs** on traditional 3-way circuits.

Comment: @Tyson - yes all from one Romex. I didn't take a picture of the bottom switch before disconnecting it :( But I'll add a picture or two of the top switch as originally wired

Comment: @Harper - sorry, "unused by the switch"

Comment: I don't think that white is neutral in this case.  In your top picture the screw on the right side showing appears to be the common terminal. The black feeding it should be always hot, regardless of switch positions.  The remaining red/black form a pair of travellers going downstairs.  If that is true, it makes the white in this case the load, not the neutral.  If this were done today the white would be marked black by wrapping it with tape, that convention was not well established in the late 80's tho.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes?

Comment: @Tyson -- this is probably more likely to be a conventional 3 way on a switch loop all the way from the light box

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that's possible, but if thats case it would be fed from above typically, not here.  It seems like this was wired as an upstairs single pole switch loop, then turned into a 3-way with a /3 from the top to downstairs.

Comment: What's the easiest way to test The @Tyson Theory? Use a multimeter to measure V AC on the top switch, between ground and that darker screw in the right of the photo? If it's ~120V when the switch & light are off then assume the white in the back is load?

Comment: With the light (load) turned ON measure voltage between the black screw of the switch, and the white to white wire nut.  If you get zero my theory is correct.

Comment: "black screw of the switch"? Do you mean the wire in the top-left or bottom-right of the attached picture?